# Association mapping in microservice

Tags: microservices, hibernate-mapping

I have two Microservices. Let's say student & library.

1. student & library - eureka clients
2. The microservices have a common DB

The scenario is - A student can issue (or take) multiple books from the library.

**In Monolithic Application**:- This will be implemented by anotating`@OneTOMany` on **List of LibraryBook** in **StudentEntity** and adding one table where we will store each book id for student.

**Currently what i have tried**
I have loose mapping (or binding ) of data between the data. I have created a table in DB with two columns **studentId** and **bookId** and when a student takes a book from library I add the bookId in the table and delete the record when book is returned.

For saving -

```java
StudentBook studentBook = new StudentBook();
studentBook.setStudentId(123);
studentBook.setBookId(456);

studentBookRepository.save(studentBook);  // studentBookRepository extends JPA Repository
```

For Deleting-

```java
studentBookRepository.deleteByBookIdAndStudentId(456,123);
```

*The problem in this implementation is that I always have to verify the bookId before saving the records.*

Is there any better way to implement this?
How to implement `@OneToMany` relationship in Microservices?
(Or can we even implement Association mapping in microservices)
(Or can we even implement Association mapping in microservices)

Comment: Can you be more specific and provide what you have tried?

Comment: @tsuz I have added the current implementation in my system.

Comment: Ideally, you want a “Rent” micro-service (ms) which keeps records of each time a student rents books. The client would verify the user exists in StudentRecord and reserve the books from LibraryBook. When that is confirmed, the client should post to Rent micro service with renting details. Similarly, the client would “return” the books by calling return action on the Rent ms, and when that is confirmed, it should put the count back in the “LibraryBook” ms. But this could be achieved without Rent ms by just adding another table in one of the two ms for now. It can be decoupled later. @devraux